# Standard Deviation and data set increasing by multiplication.

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation

Hi guys I recently started learning statistics and I'm a bit confused.
I know when a data set is multiplied by a constant, its standard deviation and mean is multiplied by the same number.

However when its multiplied by a negative constant (x), the standard deviation is multiplied by $x$ and the mean by $- x$. Why is the standard deviation not multiplied by a negative number?

Comment: Because a standard deviation is the square root of a non-negative number (the variance).  The variance is multiplied by $x^2$ so the standard deviation is multiplied by $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: If you want an intuitive way to think about it, standard deviation is a measure of spread. What would it mean for your data to be spread out a negative amount? Imagine you have the dataset $\{1,2,3\}$. Is that more spread out than $\{-1,-2,-3\}$? Or are they spread out the same amount, but with different centers?